# using typedef pointer to function in class

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I have listed different usage of pointer to function in C++ class. It probably seems useless but I want to call `combiner` member function inside the class (`useAdd`).

```
#include <iostream>

class myclass;
using namespace std;
typedef int (myclass::*myFuncType)(int, int);

class myclass
{
private:
    int a;
    int b;

public:
    ~myclass(){};

    int add(const int x1, const int x2)
    {
        return (x1 + x2);
    }
    int mult(const int x1, const int x2)
    {
        return (x1 * x2);
    }

    int combiner(const int x1, const int x2, myFuncType func)
    {
        return (this->*func)(x1, x2);
    }
    void useAdd(const int x1, const int x2)
    {
        cout << "using inside the class " << combiner(x1, x2, ??) << endl;
    }
};
/*------------------------------*/

int main()
{
    myclass classi;
    cout << classi.add(4, 5) << endl;

    myFuncType ptrName = &myclass::add;
    cout << (classi.*ptrName)(4, 5) << endl;
    cout << classi.combiner(4, 5, &myclass::add) << endl;

    // classi.useAdd(4, 5); ??

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I assume you want to ask about how to pass a pointer to a member function as argument? Well it's simple: You pass a pointer to the member function like you would any other value, with the help of the address-of operator `&`. And if that's not your question, then what is your question? Please refresh [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acquiring a pointer-to-member has the same syntax both inside and outside the class that defines the member; you need

```
cout << "using inside the class " << combiner(x1, x2, &myclass::add) << endl;
```

That is, exactly like in `main`.